# Where can I get a cover for a main supply?

Tags: electrical, uk, meter, power-supply

My house (I live in the UK) failed an electrical safety inspection because of a missing main supply cover.  I have tried using google to find one to buy but can't find anything at all.  Does anyone know how I can go about getting the right kind of cover for this?
[image: electric main]

For context, the unit is connected to the electricity meter
[image: electric meter]

UPDATE:
I reported this to UK Power Networks after the advice I got here and they booked somebody to come out 2 days from when I called.  The guy had a spare cover in his van - he collects the parts when he attends demolitions.  So it was easy in the end.

Comment: "Main supply" for what? That can't possibly be where the power from the pole comes into the house - the wires are _far_ too small for that. What product is this attached to?

Comment: The red and grey cables go into the electricity meter.  I don't know where the white one at the bottom goes.

Comment: Thanks, I've added more info and will try to find a local shop that might be able to help.

Comment: LOL, I don't think there was anything really identifiable in that pic. Maybe that's a unique meter number on there - blacking that out would have been reasonable. :)

Comment: I just thought better safe than sorry as I know nothing about it! :)

Comment: @FreeMan: It almost certainly is where the power from the "pole" (more likely underground cables) comes in - probably 60+ years old by the look of it...

Comment: @FreeMan If you take a close look at the end of the red conductor, it looks like at least 16 mm² copper (~4.5 mm in diameter, something like #6 AWG), which is enough to carry 60 A (the rating of the main fuse, the white box under the terminals). In a 230V country this is more than enough for a small to mid-sized house.

Comment: I surrender! From the picture that wire looks much smaller than I'm used to seeing as the main feeder cable in US installations. Please forgive my lack of experience. I've learned something about the rest of the world from these posts.

Comment: @FreeMan Aluminium is almost unheard of in Europe, compared to US. In addition, we have double the voltage. I have a 80m^2 flat; my incomer is 6mm^2 Cu.

Comment: @psmears About right - the meter date is 1969.

Comment: @user1908704: Haha - how did you find that out? I was just guessing...

Comment: @psmears First two digits of the meter number (in the original pic) are the year

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Some important UK context is missing from the other answers. In the UK this is know as the "Service Head" or main cut-out. It is the responsibility of the local Distribution Network Operator (DNO). Neither you, or your electricians are supposed to interfere with this and it is considered quite dangerous to do so as some of those exposed metal parts are before the 60-100A fuse that protects your property. A short circuit before the fuse could be very severe.

Therefore you should report this to your DNO saying you have exposed metal parts and is dangerous. They will likely come out the same day and replace the cover, or the head.

Your DNO depends upon where you live. Either search for it, or ring 105 to be put through to the appropriate local DNO.

Comment: This is the correct answer! The DNO is responsible for this equipment. I'm honestly surprised that the person conducting the electrical safety inspection didn't call the DNO themselves, they've left an incredibly dangerous conductor exposed.

Comment: Yeah, they should at least have directed OP to the responsible operator.

Comment: I think it's pretty unlikely (though not impossible) the DNO guy will have a matching replacement cover, there are simply too many different styles of cutout used over the years. AIUI the DNOs have a heavy adhesive backed plastic sheeting they can use to temporally cover live parts if they cannot immediately replace damaged equipment.

Comment: Doen't matter whether they can fix it or replace it - This is the DNO's problem not the home-owner's.    Further, it would have been closed with a safety wire/seal.   By passing the buck to the DNO, it also passes liability.   Most electrical network operators are incredibly responsive once a problem is reported - they don't generally muck about.

Comment: The seals are there to prevent tampering (bypassing the meter). Prepare for some tough questions from the revenue protection team of your supplier and possible fines.

Comment: There should also be seals on the incoming connections of the meter.

Comment: That looks like an old service head (AEI as written on the cutout fuse carrier was bought by GEC in 1968) and I think it likely they would replace the whole thing with a new one.  You'd also get upgraded to at least an 80A fuse and maybe 100A if the meter tails are 25mm2 (which I'm not sure they are). I expect it'll take about half an hour and since it's a safety critical fault they should do it same-day.